# Apply CSS3 transition on change of a different property

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I know with CSS3 transitions you can tell it to slowly apply a change to a property when it's changed. I'm wondering if there's a way to do the same thing, but when a different property is changed.

For example, the classic tutorial example on hover:

```
-- CSS --
#div1 { opacity: 0.2; transition: opacity 1s; }
#div1:hover { opacity: 1; }

-- HTML --
<div id="div1" style="width:200px;height:200px;background-color:#000;"></div>
```

What I'm hoping to do is apply opacity transformation like this, but when a different property is changed. Specifically, a separate library which I have no control over is showing/hiding an element the normal way, using javascript to set the `display` property. What I'd like to do is hook up to that change somehow to force it to fade in and out using `opacity`, without tapping in to the javascript that's making the call.

Is there some CSS3 magic I can do to make this happen?

(If you're wondering, it's using ASP.NET AJAX with all of its funky toolkits and extenders, so I can't really dig into their script - if it was regular jQuery or another simple javascript library making the calls, it would be much easier to work with).

Comment: I don't think you can. CSS3 transitions are performed between two states defined by selectors, and to my knowledge there is no selector that matches the `display` style property. If the code was adding/removing a class instead of setting the `display` style property, transitioning would be possible.

Comment: if you don't have access to the script that's changing the `display` then there's no way to stop it from doing that short of blocking the script.

Comment: You can add your own javascript file after the library and add your own code to the event. That way you can set up a listener.